# don't recognize this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, md5

I'm trying to start to use MD5 .js of webtoolkit. But doesn't recognize the method MD5 when i invoke from a script in jquery. What i'm doing wrong??? it's not a problem loading the js because i already checked with charles debugging proxy.

**JS**

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){

    var password = MD5($('#txtPassword').val());

    $.post("../Backend/inicisarSession.php",{password: password}, respuesta);
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
<link href="../Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/iniciarSession.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/webtoolkit.md5.js" ></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Inicio de sesión</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Inicio de Sesión</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div align="center" />
    <img src="../Styles/images/Steripharma.png" width="200" height="50"/>
    </div>
    <div align="center" />
    <div data-role="content">   
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="txtName">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="txtName" value=""  />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="txtPassword">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="password" name="name" id="txtPassword" value=""  />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="index.html" id="btnIniciarSession" data-role="button">Inciar Session</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    </div><!-- /content -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use MD5 for secure information.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it's only a example doesn't required to many security

Comment: jQuery Mobile **and** jQuery 1.6.1 ???

Comment: do you see it in the DOM - via firebug or the like? I agree - the missing script bracket is a show-stopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `>` on the `<script>` line for the md5 library.